# Cannot use awk pipe output

Tags: command-line, awk

the function `awk '!seen[$0]++'` print the new occurrences in an input pipe.

I am however unable to add a pipe after. E.g

```
my_function_with_ouput | awk '!seen[$0]++' | while read j
do
echo $j
done
```

Doesn't produce any output.

Comment: I have corrected the thread

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`awk` buffers the STDOUT stream, you need to flush the STDOUT, make it flush the stream using the `fflush()` function of GNU `awk`:

```
my_function_with_ouput | awk '!seen[$0]++ {print; fflush()}' | while ...
```

If you don't have `gawk`, take help from `stdbuf`, unbuffered STDOUT:

```
my_function_with_ouput | stdbuf -o0 awk '!seen[$0]++' | while ...
```

or make STDOUT line buffered:

```
my_function_with_ouput | stdbuf -oL awk '!seen[$0]++' | while ...
```