# Pipe stdout through sed or awk command BEFORE redirecting to file?

Tags: sed, awk, pipe, arduino, stdout

I am still kind of new to programming, but willing to learn: I am struggling with a problem in following project:
I am logging analog read-outs of an Arduino board.
The Arduino board sends tab-separated values (as a string) via following command to the serial device on my machine.

```
loop {
[...]
Serial.println(stringOfTabSeparatedValues);
Serial.flush();
}
```

The values are than retrieved from the serial device and appended (logged) in file.log on my computer through following command:

```
ttylog -f -b 9600 -d /dev/ttyACM0 >> /dir/to/file.log
```

The content of file.log looks as following:

```
value1a value2a value3a value...

value1b value2b value3b value...

value1c value2c value3c value...

...
```

This seems to work so far.
However, since I would like to link/load this file content to a spreadsheet which is updated in real time, I want to get rid of the empty lines inbetween. (Why does *println()* generate empty lines when read by ttylog in the first place?)
I would like the lines to be logged to look like following:

```
value1a value2a value3a value...
value1b value2b value3b value...
value1c value2c value3c value...
...
```

I figured I could use a pipe to modify ttylog stdout before redirecting that modified output to the destination file. Here is what I have tried:

```
ttylog -f -b 9600 -d /dev/ttyACM0 | awk 'NF' >> /dir/to/file.log
ttylog -f -b 9600 -d /dev/ttyACM0 | awk 'NF' | tee -a /dir/to/file.log
ttylog -f -b 9600 -d /dev/ttyACM0 | sed -i '/^$/d' >> /dir/to/file.log
ttylog -f -b 9600 -d /dev/ttyACM0 | sed -i '/^$/d' | tee -a /dir/to/file.log
```

Unfortunately, in those cases **nothing at all was written to file.log**. (Why?)
I noticed though, that following commands at least give my the desired output printing it to the terminal:

```
ttylog -f -b 9600 -d /dev/ttyACM0 | awk 'NF'
ttylog -f -b 9600 -d /dev/ttyACM0 | sed -i '/^$/d'
```

However I do not know how to redirect that output directly to a file. 
I figure my problem has something to do with both, awk and sed, normally using stdin and not stdout as input?
Conclusively, I tried redirecting from ttylog to awk/sed and then to the destination file:

```
ttylog -f -b 9600 -d /dev/ttyACM0 >> awk 'NF' >> /dir/to/file.log
ttylog -f -b 9600 -d /dev/ttyACM0 >> sed -i '/^$/d' >> /dir/to/file.log
```

But **here stdout was unmodified written to file.log**. (Why?)

**Is there a way to modify the output of ttylog (stdout) BEFORE redirecting that output to a file?**

Cheers and thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first attempt looks correct - you are probably just not seeing anything because the output is being buffered. See for example [Cannot use awk pipe output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830700/cannot-use-awk-pipe-output/830708#830708)

Comment: Thank You very much @steeldriver for pointing out my error. `ttylog -f -b 9600 -d /dev/ttyACM0 | awk 'NF {print; fflush()}' >> /dir/to/file.log` works like a charm!